# How to listen out for firebase notifications on any activity

Tags: android, notifications

I have followed a couple of tutorials to send notifications from firebase to an Android application, and I am able to receive the notifications no problem.

I am trying to understand 2 things:

> 1. How do I handle the receiving of a notification while the user is viewing an activity which does not process the notification?
> 2. When the app is running but is not in the foreground and I receive a notification, when I click it from the system tray the application opens up the activity which has the broadcaster defined - how do I control which activity is opened?

Here is the code from the activity which handles the notifications

```
public class DisplayNotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_notification);

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // checking for type intent filter
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                // gcm successfully registered
                // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // new push notification is received
                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                txtMessage.setText(message);
            }
        }
    };
```

If you need to see other parts of code let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I handle the receiving of a notification while the user is viewing an activity which does not process the notification?

I will try to make it as short as possible. When your app is in foreground the notifications are received in `onMessageReceived()`method of your implementation of `FirebaseMessagingService`. Now which Activity should you broadcast the event to ? Make a Base Activity class and make all your Activities extend it. In the BaseActivity you can use the Broadcast approach or try using some `Eventbus` library like i do like this:

```
@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onNotificationReceived(NotificationReceieveBean bean){

 if(bean != null){

       ViewUtils.showJobOfferSnackBar(this, bean.map);

       EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(bean);
    }



}
```

Any Activity extending the Base Activity will be able to receive the notification event. You can handle it accordingly.

> When the app is running but is not in the foreground and I receive a notification, when I click it from the system tray the application opens up the activity which has the broadcaster defined - how do I control which activity is opened?

Usually when you click the system generated notification, your first activity opens up. You have to check the data in the `Bundle` instance has the same keys as the ones you're sending from the Server, in the onCreate() example:

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(bundle != null){
        // if the below condition is true then it means you have received notification
        if(bundle.getString("notification_key_sent_from_server") != null) {
            ViewUtils.handleIncomingFCMNotification(bundle);

            finish(); // finishing the first activity since I want to go to some other activity
            return;

        }

    }
```

** **EDIT** **

```
public abstract class BaseNotificationHandlerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 protected int activityFlag = 0; // set a unique value from each extending Activity
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

 @Override
 public void onStart(){
  super.onStart();
  EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(NotificationItem notif) {
  if(activityFlag == 1){ 
   // this means Starting Activity, so handle for it particularly
       NotificationHelper notifHelper = new NotificationHelper(this);
       notifHelper.AddNotificationItem(notif);
   }
  else if(activityFlag ==2){
    // for some other Activity
    }

  }
}


public class StartingActivity extends BaseNotificationHandlerActivity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting);
  activityFlag = 1; // add unique flag for Activity here
}

 @Override
 public void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Okay - in reference to question 1 how can I handle the receiving of a notification differently for certain activities?

Comment: @andrewb, Just make a method in BaseActivity which handles the notifications, Implementing activities should override that method if they want to handle notification differently :)

Comment: you mention BaseActivit,y, in my case is this DisplayNotificationActivity?

Comment: In my answer, I have explained BaseActivity's purpose and usage. All your activities should extend it. You can name it anything you want.

Comment: I am trying to extend it but when I do the broadcast listener does not receive the notifications

Comment: I suggest using [Eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for this . These are side cases where this makes life a lot easier.

Comment: I played around with EventBus but the same thing happens - the onMessageEvent does not fire in the base class so I have to handle it in every activity

Comment: Can You Show your code of how you're doing this ? Update your question please. Without looking at your code I can't help you much.

Comment: @andrewb You should add the code to your question not my answer ;)

Comment: `onMessageEvent()` should be in the `BaseNotificationHandlerActivity`.. !! I will explain it to you later

Comment: @andrewb I've Edited my answer. It should be clear enough now.

Comment: Yeah, I had onMessageEvent in the Base class, just skipped putting in my last edit - it still does not fire. Thanks for your help though

Comment: @andrewb Are you firing it like this `Eventbus.getDefault.post(new NotificationItem());` ?